# Query no firestore para verificar item dentro de um documento

Tags: android, firebase

Estou usando o *Firebase Firestore* e estou precisando montar uma *query que verifique o seguinte dado conforme apontado na figura a seguir:

[image: Estrutura do Resultado]

Por ele estar em um *array*, dentro do meu documento, não sei como montar a *query*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que o Firebase não tem capacidade para executar tal query.

No entanto, para resolver o problema, Sugiro que você crie uma coleção "Pessoas" na raíz e coloque lá esses mesmos atributos. Adicione também o atributo "idUsuario".

Assim, a sua query ficaria:

```
db.collection("pessoas")
    .whereEqualTo("idUsuario", "Y1e8racPvbhr5RHuxkQv")
    .whereEqualTo("preso",true);
```

Comment: excelente ideia, kkkk valew